# Как выполнить foreach?

Tags: php

Не могу разобраться с синтаксисом.

Имею следующий код:

```
$element = '<select name="'.$prefix.'">'.foreach($values as $option) {.'<option value="'.$option['value'].'">Male</option>'.}.'</select>';
```

Получаю ошибку

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ParseError
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Как правильно выполнить foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
$element = '<select name="'.$prefix.'">';
foreach($values as $option) {
  $element .= '<option value="'.$option['value'].'">Male</option>';
}
$element .= '</select>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Если очень надо именно сохранить результат в переменную, то можно ещё таким способом *(но это затрудняет чтение)*:

```
$element = '<select name="'. $prefix .'">'. join(array_map(function($a){ return '<option value="' . $a['value'] . '">Male ' . $a['value'] . '</option>'; }, $values)) . '</select>';
```